# Breaking an until loop once condition is met in Ruby

Tags: ruby, loops

For example in the following code, I would want the loop to end as soon as the condition evaluates as `true`

```
x = "B"

until x == "A"
x = gets.chomp
puts "x is not equal to "A""
end
```

So if the user enters `"F"` they get the `puts` but if they enter `"A"` then the `puts` does not get outputted.

Comment: Is this just for learning purposes or is there a practical reason you would use this setup?

Comment: there is a practical reason, I would be running code that could potentially change x to true and I would want it to loop over all the code until x = true and then it stops evaluating the rest of the code. @CharlesCaldwell

Comment: Should be `puts 'x is not equal to "A"'` or `puts "x is not equal to 'A'"`

Answer (score 1):

`x = true` assigns `true` to `x` so `until x = true` is equivalent to `until true`.

So, replace `=` with `==` in the following line:

```
until x = true
```

->

```
until x == true
```

Or, it will never end.

**UPDATE**

Use following code:

```
while true
  x = gets.chomp
  break if x == 'A'
  puts 'x is not equal to "A"'
end
```

or

```
until (x = gets.chomp) == 'A'
  puts 'x is not equal to "A"'
end
```

Comment: but once I run this `a` still evaluates to `2` and not `1` like I want

Comment: maybe I used the wrong example code, I don't want to insert a specific break in the `until` after I set `x = true`. I want a loop that will `break` once `x = true` no matter where it is in the code. Is `until` not the right code for this? @falsetru

Comment: Your first line is not quite right, as `x` is indeed compared with `true` (i.e., after it is set to `true`).  How about, "`x = true` assigns true to `x`, so `until x = true` is equivalent to `until true`"?

Comment: I updated my original code to further clarify, please look @falsetru

Comment: thank you the `while` code worked best for my current problem @falsetru

Answer (score 0):

The keyword `break` will exit from a loop.

```
x = false
a = 0
b = 0

until x # is a boolean already so no need for == true
  a = 1
  b = 2
  # code here that could change state of x
  break if x # will break from loop if x == anything other than false or nil
  a = 2
  b = 1
end
```

Obviously, this is not good code but there is some useful concepts in there that you might be able to fish out.

**EDIT**

In response to your new code, it is proper use for `until` loop.

```
puts "x is not equal to 'A'" until (x = gets.chomp) == "A"
```

Comment: I updated my code in the original post to further clarify. I will try your `break if` but have a look and let me know if I am doing the right loop or if I should be doing another. Thank you! @charles_caldwell

Comment: I think your example code in your updated question should work fine (as long as you start `x` equaling something other than "A". I wrote a slightly shorter version of it.

Comment: I ran your code but once I enter `"A"` it still tells me the `puts` after and then ends. I want it to break before the `puts` if `X == "A"` @charles-caldwell

Comment: Odd. It works for me. And you are entering `A` and not `"A"`, right? Or are you trying to capture the string `"A"` instead of `A`?

Comment: i tried the above, but instead of using x as a variable, i'm using it as a call to a method: how do i call "until method_name"? i'm getting an undefined method name error. any tips would be much appreciated.

Comment: @BKSpurgeon I tried using a method in a conditional statement and it worked. I tried `until some_method`. Since you got an undefined method name error, I would suggest looking to see whether your method is defined. Look to make sure you defined your method _before_ the `until` loop. If your method is defined in another file, make sure that file is `require`'d.

Comment: Also, something to consider when using a method in a conditional statement is that a conditional (like `if`, `while`, and `until`) will consider `false` and `nil` as false. It will consider everything else as true. So, I would suggest explicitly returning a value from the method. Since a method always returns a value, and that value is always the last thing evaluated, not explicitly returning a value might give you odd results in your conditional. Just my two cents.

Comment: @CharlesCaldwell thank you - you were correct, method was defined after instead of before. chrs